# Cucumber test - could not find classs cucumber.api.cli.Main

Tags: java, cucumber, code-coverage

Since a couple of days, when I try to exectue my cucumber tests, I always receive an error "could not find classs cucumber.api.cli.Main".
Nothing has been changed in my config (as far as know).

> [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli)
> @acceptance-tests --- Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la
> classe principale cucumber.api.cli.Main [ERROR] Command execution
> failed.

Strage behaviour : if I'm not able to execute the test via the run command :

[Execute with run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omsHv.png)

I'm able to execute the test with the command run with coverage :

[Execute with run with coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrEPR.png)

But as I have to debug my tests, the run with coverage is not very helpful.
Do you have any idea to solve this issue?
I've found the class cucumber.api.cli.Main in my dependecies.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try checking the differences in the run configuration between both

Comment: Sounds like your IDE is confused. Make sure you only have a single cucumber version in your (transitive) dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the root cause of my issue, it was due to a wrong option in my intelij settings like describe here :

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-261546/Run-specific-Cucumber-scenario-builds-the-whole-project-running-tests-in-all-suite-files-in-the-project

> I guess I may find your issue cause here. Do you enable the Delegate
> IDE build/run actions to maven option in Preference | Build,
> Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner? Please try to
> disable it to see if it helps.